# Repeating UIFont and UIColor on Scroll UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I`m having a problem and I created a simple mvp to show for you guys.

When I scroll on the table other index gets the color and the font.

**Exemple:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    var texto: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0

        texto.append("Title 1")
        texto.append("Content 1")
        texto.append("Read More 1")

        texto.append("Title 2")
        texto.append("Content 2")
        texto.append("Read More 2")

        texto.append("Title 3")
        texto.append("Content 3")
        texto.append("Read More 3")

        texto.append("Title 4")
        texto.append("Content 4")
        texto.append("Read More 4")

        texto.append("Title 5")
        texto.append("Content 5")
        texto.append("Read More 5")

        texto.append("Title 6")
        texto.append("Content 6")
        texto.append("Read More 6")

        texto.append("Title 7")
        texto.append("Content 7")
        texto.append("Read More 7")

        self.tableView!.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.texto.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2")! as UITableViewCell

        if [0,3].contains(indexPath.row){
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 28)
        }
        if [2,5].contains(indexPath.row){
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(hue: 0.575, saturation: 1, brightness: 0.89, alpha: 1.0)

        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.texto[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }


}
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I write, if index of texto is 0 or 3 they get font changed,  but when i use the scroll other index`s get the same font too.

## Right way!

[image]

## Wrong way!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells get reused. When you set a cell's attribute for one condition, you need to reset it for the other conditions. Update your code to something like this:

```
    if [0,3].contains(indexPath.row){
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 28)
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.font = // Some default font
    }
    if [2,5].contains(indexPath.row){
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(hue: 0.575, saturation: 1, brightness: 0.89, alpha: 1.0)
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = // some default color
    }
```

Comment: I dont know how is the default font, have some way to know?

Comment: Use `UIFont systemFontOfSize`. Experiment with the size. Maybe 16 or 17?

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewCell`s get reused, so you will need to either:

A - Reset `.font` and `.textColor` to the default values after you dequeue the cell

or

B - Add an `else` block to each `if` statement that resets the `.font` or `.textColor` to the default value